# second line in list attributed text is not aligned

Tags: ios

I am trying to show html data in uilabel and convert it to attribute string but the second line of the  list is not aligned , is there in any other method or document attributes to add to make the second line of the list aligned the code i used is

```
let attributedText = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the `css` definitions in your html string / data.

This is my result:

[image]

Using this simple example code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var str = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>"
    str += "<ul>"
    str += "<li>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</li>"
    str += "<li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>"
    str += "<li>Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda.</li>"
    str += "</ul>"

    let htmlData = Data(str.utf8)

    if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
        theLabel.attributedText = attributedString
    }

}
```